# How to add two hh:mm:ss format and get hh:mm:ss

Tags: momentjs, angular-moment, moment-timezone, angular2-moment

I have below format of date and need a beloe o.p in momen

```
 var myDate="2019-01-26"; 
    console.log(moment(myDate,'YYYY-MM-DD 00:00:00').add("2019-01-26 04:00");
```

expected o/p be  2019-01-26 04:00:00

Comment: Mohammed, the momentjs docs are really good. https://momentjs.com/docs/

Answer (score 1):

Based on this, and your previous similar questions it seems that you are trying to add a specific amount of time to a moment-defined date.  Perhaps the solution is simpler than you expect.  The "add" method takes two arguments; a number representing the quantity to be added, and the type of unit (weeks, days, hours, etc.)

```
var myDate="2019-01-26"; 
console.log(moment(myDate,'YYYY-MM-DD 00:00:00').add(4, "hours");
```

seems to return the value you are looking for.  the momentjs documentation is excellent.  https://momentjs.com/docs/

Comment: Although this answer may help OP, consider to improve your answer by providing steps taken in to solve problem